# Обращение к первому элементу строки display: grid;

Tags: css, html5, css-grid, grid

Есть у меня такой HTML:
Сейчас там расположена 1 строка на 13 элементов, таких строк будет 6

```
<div class="site-size__grid-grif">
        <div class="grid-grif__item">
            <span class="item__middle-line"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
        <div class="grid-grif__item"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS для grid:

```
.site-size__grid-grif {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(13, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 50px);
}
```

Вопрос в том, как мне обратиться к первому элементу первой строки и к последнему элементу последней строки? Или к n-элементу n-строки?

Можно в принципе повесить классы, так как грид объявлен явно, но может есть какое-то поизящнее решение?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RifmaMan - действительно подсказал выход, а я сразу не сообразил. Так как грид фиксированн то мы можем обращаться к элементам используя их порядковый номер к примеру к первому

```
nth-child(1)
```

к последнему

```
nth-child(13)
```

к первому элементу второй строки

```
nth-child(14)
```

и т.д.